# Does glob() hates square brackets?

Tags: php, glob

```
glob("somemapname/*.*"); is working
glob("[134]/*.*"); is NOT working
```

Both maps (somemapname and [134]) do exist.

What's wrong?

Comment: `glob("[134]/*.*")` is like combining `glob("1/*.*")`, `glob("3/*.*")`, and `glob("4/*.*")`. The square brackets aren't treated literally.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets define a list of possibilities. They are special characters in a glob expression. What you can do is escape `\` those special brackets.

```
glob('\[134\]/*.*');
```

Comment: [[]134[]]/*.*   is WORKING, yes!